# A beracha on the "Great conjunction"?

Tags: halacha, blessing, astronomy

Tonight (or earlier tonight in Israel) the planets Jupiter and Saturn come so close that one might think that they are a single star. Is this occasion to say the beracha of עושה מעשה בראשית? It is not listed as one of the occasions to make the beracha, but is it similar to a shooting star or comet ([O.C. 227](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.227.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), or to the phoneme of חמה בתקופתו, when the sun (or the zodiac) is in its "original location" when a beracha is made once in 28 years ([O.C. 229](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.229.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))?

Comment: I don't see any similarly. Why is this similar?

Comment: Impressive astronomical phenomena

Comment: Is this impressive? Stars move around all the time. This is nothing new, bright, or flashy. There's no sudden movement. It's not even so rare (every 20 years or so). What is impressive about it? How is it similar to the things that get blessings? Sure newspapers may have fun writing about it, they'll also write a piece about a "supermoon" every few months like they just discovered it

Comment: @Mordechai One is supposed to make a brocho on every planet like on the moon. I dont know why it is not done today.

Comment: @interested - please source that "ruling" - _One is supposed to make a brocho on every planet_ and describe the brocho.

Comment: @DannySchoemann 229.2 I dont make things up!

Comment: @interested - I never claimed you did. Completely forgot about https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.229.2 - any idea when it would actually be, on a calendar? None of the Meforshim give me dates. And of course the MB says וכהיום אין נוהגין העולם בזה but doesn't elaborate.

Comment: @Danny the bracha is on the heliacal rising of aries and the planets moving into aries. If you see it, say a bracha. There's no calendar for it other than what astronomers can calculate for you. But don't be surprised that you've never said it if you, like 99% of the western world, can't even identify aries in the night sky.

Comment: @DoubleAA - that's what I'm puzzled about - why isn't it calculated for us (can't be that complicated for the gurus) the same way Birkat haChamo and Start/End times of Kidush Levono are calculated. Then we could all join in the Brocho. (And no, I cannot identify Aries yet. Recently started trying to identify the planets. City skies are not fun.)

Comment: @Danny those calculations are approximations which is a problem because now a millennium later birkat hachamma as calculated isn't actually at the equinox or that close to it. Big problem. Twould be better for there not to have been a calculation. The molad was necessary for a fixed and imperfect calendar, but using it for kiddush levana is again a problematic and questionable extension. Rishonim already discuss what happens if there's an eclipse before when the molad says the time is up.